# Routing in React JS on click

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am new to React and I want to navigate to another component on button click. I just want to perform a simple routing. This is the code that I tried. But I am not able to route it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Hello from './HelloComponent';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.try = this.try.bind(this)
  }
  try = () => {
    alert();
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">

          <button id="b1" onClick={this.try}>Click me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Please help me with this code to perform basic routing in react JS

Comment: Check this for [Basic routing example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

Comment: @NarendraJadhav This is for links ,not on button click

Comment: I know but this will help you to achive your requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot return JSX to onClick handler since it won't do anything with it.

You need to configure your Routes in render in advance and use `history.push` to change the Route

Below is a sample code that you can refer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import Hello from './HelloComponent';
class App extends Component {
  try = () => {
      this.props.history.push('/hello');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
            <button id="b1" onClick ={this.try}>Click me</button>
            <Route path="/hello" component={Hello}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default () => (
   <div>
      <Router>
           <Route component={App} />
      </Router>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Why do we export Route component App here?

Comment: The component that uses Routes must be wrapped in Router and hence exporting a functional component here

Comment: Is there any way to export Router? Suppose if I already have an export in my code like,

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {signOut}),
translate('SampleApp')
)(SampleApp);
Where will I add this Router component?

Comment: Ideally you will have only one Router component in your code and it will be at the top most level. I recommend that you read the react-router documentation once. They provide a good deal of information

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you look at the [doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

`<Route path="/hello" component={Hello}/>` will display the component Hello exactly where the `<Route/>` is, but I think your function will do nothing here as it returns a `<div>` but where does it go?

You need some sort of "higher" component that will render your routes, then call a `<Link/>`

Then try nesting the button inside the `<Link/>` ?

```
<Link to="/??">
     <button id="b1">
          Click me
     </button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a demo that brings it all together. It has three files **App.js, About.js, Contacts.js**. To Navigate to any component, you need to add its route in App.js, Then depending on the location of your button (About.js), wrap it with **Link** that helps the element navigate to the specified route. When clicked, the Contacts component should be loaded. Hope this helps. [code demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wood-z0p2j?file=/src/Contacts.js:0-106)

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./About";
import Contact from "./Contacts";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={About} exact />
        <Route path="/contacts" component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry.
      </p>
      <Link to="/contacts">
        <button>click me</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
export default About;
```

**Contacts.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Contact() {
  return <div>Call me!!</div>;
}
export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
try = () => {
             alert();
            <div>
              <Router>
                   <Route path="/hello" component={Hello}/>
              </Router>
            </div>
           }
```

your just pushing the route and it's not a action to take you to different page

bellow code will work fine and it's good practice to place router in separate  component. [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlw0qj0m8m) you can find this code in codesandbox

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function RouterComponet() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/user" component={User} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  onClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/user");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App component</h1>
        <a onClick={this.onClick} className="link">
          click here
        </a>{" "}
        to user page
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class User extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  onClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>User Componet</h1>
        <a onClick={this.onClick} className="link">
          click here
        </a>{" "}
        to back
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<RouterComponet />, rootElement);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first SO post on google, so I'd like answer the  question with updated coding style and answer:

**From react v6 you use the `useNavigation` hook**. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274942/6702598))

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


export const MyComponent = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
            <>
                    <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                    navigate('/');
                            }}
                    >
                            click me
                    </button>
            </>
    );
};
```