# How to properly use useHistory () from react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How to use `useHistory()` correctly? I can't make the transition from one react component to another.
According to the instructions from the React documentation and also here on Stack Overflow, I cannot make the transition from App.js to MyComponent.js.

For example - I am trying

```
/* **App.js ** */
/* Import modules */
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; // version 5.2.0

function App()
{
    let history = useHistory ();
    const handleClick = () => {
       history.push ('./pages/MyComponent');
    }    

    return (
       <div className="App">
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Next page ==></button>
       </div>
    );
}
```

I also tested this example, but the output throws the following error when the button is pressed:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Does something seem to be leaking to me or is there a mistake on Babel's side?

Project react structure:

```
+ Root/
    + src/
        - App.js
        - index.js
        + pages/
            - MyComponent.js
```

Comment: Could it be that you have a space between `push` and the parentheses?

Comment: There is no mistake. (I tried it). @BlackMath

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't just use the `useHistory` hook to redirect to another page.
You need to properly set up your application in order to use React Router. Look at their examples starting from this https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

You need to wrap your entire application with `<BrowserRouter />` which will give the history object you are looking for through the hook.

By the way, you don't give a relative file path to history.push as an argument, you must give a valid route that you typically setup using `<Route />` component

Answer (score 107):

This has changed in v6, useHistory is now useNavigate and we can use it as follows:

instead of:

```
const history = useHistory()
history.push('/')
```

we now use:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate('/')
```

Comment: can i navigate i step back , like prev page using useHistory ?

Comment: useHistory() is dead now, don't use it

Comment: @HibaHasan I am using ^5.3.0 react-router-dom still face same issue

Comment: @HowtoProgram Pass the delta you want to go in the history stack. For example, navigate(-1) is equivalent to hitting the back button.

Answer (score 5):

Using React 17.0>, this works for me:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();
history.push("/home");
```

I've reached too much to find this correctly use of the useHistory function.
Try and answer this post for feedback.

Answer (score 2):

**useHistory is replaced by useNavigate in react-router-dom v6**

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/about')
```

For reference,

```
import './App.css'
import About from './Components/About'
import Profile from './Components/Profile'
import { Routes, Route,useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  const navigate=useNavigate()
  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={()=>navigate('/about')}>about me</button>
       <button onClick={()=>navigate('/profile')}>profile</button>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<About/>} path='/about' />
          <Route element={<Profile/>} path='/profile' />
        </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use it with react-router-dom. set your router config and then push it to that path. you can get more information by looking at documentation.

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config

do not forget to set your switch components and your exact for root path.

Comment: we can't see his routes. 
app.js usually contain that Routes and there is a route that sends you to the first component. it seems he is trying to get history from the first component without set any routes.

Comment: i agree. he is using relative path not absolute.

Comment: ya he can use the withRouter but there is no sue if you build stuff the right way

Comment: I updated the question and added the tree structure of the project. @TalOrlanczyk

Answer (score 1):

Using `history.replace('/<route-name>')` also works.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the problem is that he doesn't have `history` in scope in the first place, not that the push method isn't working and was looking for an alternative method. In his case, neither push nor replace would work.

Answer (score 1):

When you are applying history.push, is that your path name? history.push('/pathname') is the process I guess.
You can see here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 1):

it's not supported anymore in 'react-router-dom', i try this and it's working good :

```js
const goBack = () => {
    window.history.back();
  };
```