# I have a problem to redirect to another page in React js

Tags: reactjs

I want to go to another page when I click on the button and I try this code but I got this error
“TypeError:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘ push’)”

How I can solve it  problem?
Can anyone help me?

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function app() {
  let history = useHistory();
  const redirect = () => {
    history.push('/pathOfMyPage ');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={redirect}>Click Here </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you perhaps using react-router v6?

Comment: Could it be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839059/9124424

Comment: `cat package.json | grep react-router`

Comment: Can you show how you are using this function? I find it strange that it's a lower case name. React components, usable in JSX, must be upper case.

Answer (score 0):

In react-router 6, the current version you'll get if you just run `npm install react-router`, useHistory no longer seems to exist. It seems you can use `[useNavigate][1]` instead:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const redirect = () => {
    navigate("/pathOfMyPage", { replace: false });
  }
```

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",